# Can I make section headers automatically break multicols?

Tags: sectioning, multicol

I have a whole document written up, and I would now like to format it in two columns.

However, I rely heavily on headers like `\section`, and would like these headers to *not* be in the columns. In other words, the two-column text should end in the middle of the page, the section title should appear, then the two-column text should start back up again.

I can get the desired effect by specifically ending the `multicol` environment, then starting it again:

```
...
\end{multicol}

\begin{multicol}{2}[\section{Section Name Here}]
...
```

But it'll be tedious to apply this to every single heading in my document, and then to go through and modify every instance if I change the number of columns.

Is there a way to make this happen automatically, perhaps by modifying the definitions of `\section`, `\subsection`, and so on, or using `titlesec`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't quite as simple as I first thought, although the test of `\@currenvir` was probably unneeded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\let\oldsection=\section
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@ifnextchar*\oldsection\newsection}% handle \section*

\newcommand{\newsection}[2][\empty]{% #1=short title (optonsl), #2=title
  \def\test{multicols}%
  \ifx\@currenvir\test
    \end{multicols}\begin{multicols}{2}[{%
      \ifx\empty#1\relax
        \oldsection{#2}%
      \else
        \oldsection[#1]{#2}%
      \fi}]%
  \else
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
      \oldsection{#2}%
    \else
      \oldsection[#1]{#2}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section[Sec 2]{Second section}
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Unnumbered sections (`\section*`) don't span the two columns with this implementation. From the question, I had understood they should, but it was rather unclear in this respect.

Comment: @frougon - I only bothered with \section* since I added the \tableofcontents to test the short title.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \draconis_start_multicols_env:nn #1#2
  {
    \begin{multicols}{#1}[{#2}]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \draconis_start_multicols_env:nn { nV }

\tl_new:N \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \draconis_startsection:Nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \tl_if_eq:nnF {#4} { first } { \end{multicols} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl { \section }

    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl
      {
        \IfBooleanT {#1} { * }                 % star form
        \IfValueT {#2} { [ \exp_not:n {#2} ] } % title for toc and headers
        { \exp_not:n {#3} }                    % title
      }

    % This 2 is the number of columns (passed to 'multicols')
    \draconis_start_multicols_env:nV {2} \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \startsection { s o m O{} }
  {
    \draconis_startsection:Nnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \stoplastsection { }
  {
    \end{multicols}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\startsection{First section}[first]
\lipsum[1-3]

\startsection[Short title]{Second section}
\lipsum[4-6]

\startsection*{Unnumbered section}
\lipsum[7-9]

\startsection{Third section}
\lipsum[10-12]

\stoplastsection

\end{document}
```

My `\startsection` works like `\section` (including the star form), except it has the `multicols` wrapping you want and accepts an optional, final argument: if the final argument is `first`, then `\startsection` doesn't insert `\end{multicols}` (otherwise, that is the first thing it puts in the input stream).

---

Page 1

[image: Page 1]

---

Page 2

[image: Page 2]

---

Page 3

[image: Page 3]

If you don't mind:

- starting an empty `multicols` environment before the first section (hidden by the implementation, but done);
- repeating the number of columns in several parts of the document (I had understood from your question that you wanted to avoid that, but apparently not), and;
- explicitly opening and closing the `multicols` environment after `\begin{document}`,

it is easy to adapt the above solution to look precisely the way you like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \draconis_orig_section \section

\cs_new_protected:Npn \draconis_start_multicols_env:nn #1#2
  {
    \begin{multicols}{#1}[{#2}]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \draconis_start_multicols_env:nn { nV }

\tl_new:N \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \draconis_startsection:Nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \tl_if_eq:nnF {#4} { first } { \end{multicols} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl { \draconis_orig_section }

    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl
      {
        \IfBooleanT {#1} { * }                 % star form
        \IfValueT {#2} { [ \exp_not:n {#2} ] } % title for toc and headers
        { \exp_not:n {#3} }                    % title
      }

    % This 2 is the number of columns (passed to 'multicols')
    \draconis_start_multicols_env:nV {2} \l__draconis_sectioning_command_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \startsection { s o m O{} }
  {
    \draconis_startsection:Nnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4}
  }

% Replace \section with \startsection (ugh...)
\cs_set_eq:NN \section \startsection

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section[Short title]{Second section}
\lipsum[4-6]

\section*{This is the title of an unnumbered section}
\lipsum[7-9]

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[10-12]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note that this implementation does work with `\section*`, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of unnumbered section]